# c# Form not completely repainting in RDP session

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing, rdp

I have a strange problem and I can't seem to figure out a solution.
I have a windows forms application written in C# .net4.0.
In this application, there's a panel where i draw a chart on.
This chart is drawn on the "Paint" event of the panel.

There's also a button which launches another application on top of this application which displays other information
All of this works fine, untill I close the opened application.
When I Close it, i see my first application again but parts of it haven't been repainted.
It seems that the panel with the chart repainted correctly, the rest of it's container panel didn't.
I removed the "Paint" event of the Panel with the chart as a test and then, everything worked fine (offcourse no chart was drawn)

Strangly, I only do have this problem when the programs are in an RDP session.
On my local pc, everything works/refreshes fine.

If anybody can help me on this, it would be very much appreciated!!

For clarity I have added screenshots below:
[image: Step 1: opening the parent program]
[image: Step 2: opening the child program]
[image: Step 3: parent form does not repaint properly]

Answer (score 0):

we have a lot of rendering problems on RDP too.
Try setting the values mentioned here:

http://blog.tedd.no/2011/04/28/optimizing-rdp-for-casual-use-windows-7-sp1-remotefx/

Also we have implemented additional refreshes when using our application over rdp, although weird, it seems to help. We haven't found a really good and clean solution yet.
You can also alter RDP behavior in the options menu when you start the RDP session. We are using transparency, for example, and had to turn of bitmap caching.